# Is it wrong to say ‘sourness is the taste’?

Tags: abstract-nouns

> Sourness is the taste that detects acidity.
>
> from [Wikipedia: Taste#Sourness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste#Sourness).

I think it’s like saying redness is the color, not red is the color. Should it be ‘sour taste’?

Comment: 'Bitterness' is definitely the noun for bitter, but '-ness' for all the others sounds strange to me. I'd go so far as to say that 'sour' is the noun for 'sour' (or at least it is more natural than with '-ness'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sourness%20is%20the%20taste%2C%20sour%20is%20the%20taste&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csour%20is%20the%20taste%3B%2Cc0) completely rules out ***sourness is the taste*** in favour of ***sour is the taste***. And yes, you could argue that *sourness* is a *quality* related to taste.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sourness) defines it as

> the quality of having a sour taste.

But [Oxford Leaner's dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sourness) says that it is

> a taste like that of a lemon or of fruit that is not ready to eat

whereas other [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/sourness) send you straight to "see the definition of" ***sour***.

I personally agree that ***sourness*** is the *quality* of being/tasting sour, not the taste itself, so it does look like ***Sour is the taste that detects acidity*** would be a better formulation.

Comment: The distinction between "sense of taste" and "property" does seem to be the key.  I would have no problem with: "I tasted the new dish and something is not right. I think *sourness is the taste* that's missing."

Comment: I just don’t like the whole idea of taste *detecting* acidity.  Acidity  may register as a sour taste.  But the person does the detecting using their tastebuds.

Comment: @Jim: I agree! I don't know why all sites give this definition. Do they all borrow it from Wikipedia and spread it around? Who knows...